# Можно ли как-то на ткинтере сделать сообщение с выбором ответа?

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне нужно сделать вывод сообщения на `tkinter` (по типу `showinfo`) где задаётся вопрос: *Принимаете ли вы условия соглашения?*, а внизу две кнопки: **Да**, **Нет** (на которые может нажать пользователь). Помогите.

Comment: Как-то можно сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю Вы хотите сделать кнопку на `tkinter`, при нажатии на которую, пользователь выбирает, согласен ли он с условиями соглашения.

Для этого нам понадобятся функции `askyesnocancel()` и `showinfo()` из модуля  `tkinter.messagebox`.

Импортируем их: `from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo, askyesnocancel`.

Дальше мы "запихиваем" команду для кнопки в функцию и там просто сравниваем условием `if` ответы "да, нет, отмена".

Полный код:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from tkinter.messagebox import askyesnocancel

root=Tk()


root.title('Условия соглашения')
root.geometry('500x500')



def message_choice():
    result =  askyesnocancel(title="Условия соглашения", message="Вы принимаете условия соглашения?")
    if result==None: showinfo(title="Условия соглашения", 
message="Операция приостановлена")
    elif result: showinfo(title="Условия соглашения", 
message="Успешно")
    else : showinfo(title="Условия соглашения", 
message="Неудачно")



ttk.Button(text='click', width=6, height=2, 
command=message_choice).pack(anchor='center', 
expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Немного поизучал эту команду и понял что команда то `ask`, а к ней можно уже приписывать кнопки (по типу ок, отмена, да, нет, повтор)

Comment: @Arter345 верно